# Сумма параметров функции рекурсивно

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Не получается найти сумму аргументов функции с помощью рекурсии.
если передан массив, то понял как это делается (уже была такая тема здесь),если без рекурсии, то тоже не возникает проблем.

пробую передать параметры через спред оператор, но выдает ошибку.
подскажите, что делаю не так?

```js
let sum = 0;
let i = 0;

function summ(...arr) {
  if (arr.length !== i) {
    sum = sum + summ(arr[i])
    i++;
    return sum
  } else return sum
}
summ(5, 7, 10, 1, 39)
```

Comment: в ошибке все написано

Comment: Вы переполнили `call stack`, вызвав функцию рекурсивно более 10000 раз

Comment: а как это исправить?

Comment: _если передан массив, то понял как это делается_ - в случае со `spread` все работает то же самое, просто в параметрах и месте вызова добавляются `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так попробуйте, может то или нет

```js
function summ(...arr) {
  console.log(`called sum with params (${arr})`);
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
   return arr[0] + summ(...arr.slice(1));
  }
}

console.log(`sum of (5, 7, 10, 1, 39) = ${summ(5, 7, 10, 1, 39)}`)
```

Comment: Да, именно то, о чем спрашивал. Огромное спасибо, буду разбираться, как это работает))

Answer (score 0):

Давайте посмотрим, как работает функция для вашего массива `summ(5, 7, 10, 1, 39)`

```
function summ(...arr) {
  if (arr.length !== i) { // 5 != 0 - ок
    sum = sum + summ(arr[i]) // далее будет вызван summ(5)
```

для `summ(5)`

```
 if (arr.length !== i) { // 1 != 0 - ок
    sum = sum + summ(arr[i]) // и снова вызов summ(5)
```

И так происходит циклично до переполнения стека

Comment: так я же делаю i++. Думал, arr[i] каждый раз будет меняться. разве нет?

Comment: строка `i++;` не выполняется даже, потому как вы вызываете рекурсивно `summ(arr[i])`. У вас ведь в строке `sum = sum + summ(arr[i])` заново происходит вызов функции

Comment: можете подсказать, как это исправить? уже мозг сломал с этой рекурсией =)

Comment: @Дмитрий, хорошее решение можно найти здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425581/sum-of-an-array-using-recursion-javascript/37425626

Comment: так это немного не то, о чем я спрашивал =) если передается массив в параметры - я знаю, как вычислить результат через рекурсию. Интересует не массив, именно произвольное кол-во параметров. пробовал через ...arr, но не выходит